# Google model-viwer is looking for my 3d model letter-by-letter instead of the whole source at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost

Google model-viewer is searching for my model letter by letter which makes the model load late and after an ugly white box is displayed.

I can see the error on the console and have attached the screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/p65lh1

```
<model-viewer
   onclick="playAudio()"
   onload="playAudio()"
   class="model"
   src="a.glb"
   style="cursor: grab"
   autoplay
   auto-rotate camera-controls
   background-color="black"
   shadow-intensity="1">
</model-viewer>
```

I want the model to load normally without any white box and quickly.

Comment: I have hosted the site on ( https://divided7.github.io/boronhubforked/) ... type in 3d model and look at the console for the error too.